# Want to replace "<p>&nbsp;</p>" with "<p></p>" on new paragraph button click in telerik rad editor

Tags: telerik, editor, rad, radeditor

When we use New paragraph button in telerik rad editor it puts "<p>&nbsp;</p>". 
Just Want to replace "<p>&nbsp;</p>" with "<p></p>" on new paragraph button click in telerik rad editor.

Answer (score 1):

The `&nbsp;` entity inside the paragraph tags is added on purpose. If you remove it the browser won't be able to render the new line.

What I also noticed when testing the requested behavior is that IE automatically fills the contents of the empty

tags with `&nbsp;` even when the content filters of the editor are disabled: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx.

I was able to reproduce this behavior in other WYSIWYG editors as well as in an editable iframe, which means that this is a browser behavior.